# Closed paths, closed trails and traces

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, traces

Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of a (non-oriented) graph $\Gamma$. Then $\textrm{Tr} A^k$ equals both the sum $\sum_i \lambda_i^k$ of $k$th powers of eigenvalues of $A$, on the one hand, and the number of closed paths of length $k$ in $\Gamma$, on the other hand.
If we have a good bound on the latter, then we have a good bound on the former. For $k$ even, a good bound on the former quantity implies that there aren't too many large eigenvalues $\lambda_i$.

What happens if we have an even better bound on closed trails of length $k$, that is, closed paths where no edges are repeated?
Or what happens if we can give a very good bound on the number of closed paths that neither backtrack (i.e., an edge is never followed by its inverse) nor have long repeated sequences of edges (as in, an edge sequence $$(v_0,v_1), (v_1,v_2),\dotsc, (v_{l-1},v_l)$$ appearing at least twice, where $l$ is not that much smaller than $k$)? Can we then say something stronger about $A$?

Here, by "a very good bound", I mean a bound that is stronger ( = smaller) than would be possible for the number of closed paths of length $k$: there are always plenty of backtracking closed paths (at least $d^{k/2}$ starting from a vertex of degree $d$).

(I've asked related questions in the recent past: see [Closed paths, traces and spectra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363786/closed-paths-traces-and-spectra) and [Ihara zeta function and closed paths and trails](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/363969/ihara-zeta-function-and-closed-paths-and-trails) .)

Comment: Maybe you are familiar with all this, but you might like to check out (e.g.) Bordenave's recent simpler proof of Friedman's theorem, that in a random d-regular graph all nontrivial eigenvalues are at most 2sqrt(d-1)+o(1) with high probability.  https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.04482  It contains a number of useful ideas, including bounding eigenvalues using Ihara--Bass and the non-backtracking operator, bounding only nontracking walks in which each edge is used at least twice, and getting improved bounds when the graph doesn't have two cycles in any small neighborhood.

Comment: @Ryan O'Donnell Actually, I hadn't read it - thanks. In the context I'm working on, I also manage to exclude nontracking walks in which an edge is used only once. I wonder whether the trick is the same - where does Bordenave does this?

Comment: He doesn't exactly, but what he does is morally strictly harder than handling random d-regular graphs with random edge signs. In the latter case, closed walks where every edge is used an even number of times naturally arise. See, e

Comment: Your comment was cut off?

Comment: e.g. my paper with Mohanty and Paredes on explicit Ramanujan graphs (linked on my homepage -- sorry, am typing this on my phone)